# Which timeout has TIBCO EMS while waiting for acknowledge?

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems

We are developing a solution using TIBCO-EMS, and we have a question about its behaviour.

When using CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE mode to connect, the client acknowledges the received message. We'd like to know for how long does TIBCO wait for acknowledgement, and if this time is configurable by the system admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the EMS server waits forever for the acknowledgement of the message.

As long as the session is still alive, the transaction will not be discarded and the server waits for an acknowledgement or rollback.

There is however a setting within the server `disconnect_non_acking_consumers` where the client will be disconnected, if there are more pending messages (not acknowledged) then the queue limit does allow to store (`maxbytes`, `maxmsgs`). In this case, the server sends a connection reset to get rid of the client.

Sadly the documentation doesn't state this explicitly and the only public record I found was a knowledge base entry: https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Tibco-KnowledgeArticle-Article-33925

Comment: Very useful answer. Can you provide links or references? I couldn't find anything about default behaviour in this case in official docs.

Comment: Sadly the documentation doesn't state this explicitly and the only public record I found was a knowledge base entry: https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Tibco-KnowledgeArticle-Article-33925

Comment: Great! Should reference that in your answer

Comment: follow this url for explicit documentation on this : https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/7.0.0-august-2012/TIB_ems_7.0.0_relnotes.pdf